# How Can I Classify A Photo From the Internet Using Tensorflow On Android

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm creating a project for school which requires using AI to classify images for the blind. For this project, I have used a microcontroller to store the images on a webserver for a phone to then download and classify. I have been unable to find the documentation on the Tensorflow Java wrapper necessary to run inference on a photo once it is already downloaded.

In simpler terms, can someone please help me find out how to classify an image once it is downloaded on an Android phone?

I've already tried writing the app with C++, with no luck as I do not have much experience

Comment: Let me google that for you. https://medium.com/@daj/creating-an-image-classifier-on-android-using-tensorflow-part-1-513d9c10fa6a

Comment: @android_Muncher, I've seen that article, but I'd like to classify from a file saved on the device instead of using the camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it doesn't have to be Tenserflow, you can try with google Firebase - it is easy to implement, and on device processing is free while cloud-vision-api is free for up to 1000 uses.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/label-images